# how to efficiently combine CP solver time limit with solution callback

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

I'd like to configure the `ortools` `CP_Solver`

The solver is defined as below:

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
```

such that:

- First, run for `time_limit_1`. If solution(s) are found, return the best solution.
- If no solution was found, continue until either conditions are met:
  (a) a solution is found
  (b) `time_limit_2` is reached without a solution

My current method is painfully inefficient.

First, I set `solver.parameters.max_time_in_seconds = time_limit_1`
Once the limit is reached with no solution, my solver start from scratch again. This time it uses the `stop_after_first_solution` parameter to break at the first solution found.

Is there anyway to make the second search to start from where the first one left off?

Comment: What do you mean by "CP solver"? Please spell out terms explicitly; that ensures everyone is answering the same question, and if the question becomes useful for others then it will be easier to search for.

Comment: It looks like you could use a [`CpSolverSolutionCallback`](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver#add_the_solution_printer).

Answer (score 0):

Just set a time limit of limit1 + limit2.

Then add a solution_callback that will abort if a solution is found after limit1.